# using the comment system on a page that isn't associated with one entry

Tags: expressionengine

I would like to have comments enabled for a page that loops through entries of each categories and displays a summary (essentially a start page) with comments at the bottom. How can I make use of the commenting system in such cases where it is not a particular entry?

Comment: Please clarify.  Do you want a 'category' page that displays all the entries for that category along with the comments for for each entry?  OR do you want (as Philip seems to think below) that you want to be able to collect and display comments on the category itself?

Comment: The latter, comments for the category itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use ee for comments? If not try disqus.

If that's not an option you'll need to create a ee entry for each category to allow commenting. One possible way to do this would be to create an entry for each category and then use custom category fields and create a cat-entry-I'd field to hold the categories entry. This